# Laravel: how to create a routes/console.php entry to a custom class function?

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make a new custom entry in the /routes/console.php file so I can create a user from the cli.

I have a custom function that can create a user in \app\Http\Controllers\UserManagement
It's called createUser() and accepts 3 params ($user,$email,$password)

So far I have

Artisan::command('createuser {$user} {$email} {$password}', function ($user,$email,$password) {
$this->createUser($user,$email,$password);
})->describe('Create a user via the CLI');

Currently this errors with

> Too few arguments to function
> Illuminate\Foundation\Console\ClosureCommand::__construct(), 1 passed
> in
> \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\ProviderRepository.php
> on line 208   and exactly 2 expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to [type hint](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#type-hinting-dependencies) the dependency on my class.

```
use App\Http\Controllers\UserManagerController;

Artisan::command('createuser {user} {email} {password}', function (UserManagerController $ref, $user, $email, $password) {
    $ref->createUser($user, $email, $password);
})->describe('Create a user via the CLI');
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the $ from the first parameter.
Should look like this

```
Artisan::command('createuser {user} {email} {password}', function ($user, $email, $password) {
    $this->createUser($user, $email, $password);
})->describe('Create a user via the CLI');
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  It still doesn't work.  I get exactly the same error still.   This is something syntax related in regards to closure that I don't understand.  Any ideas?